# Should I use multiple threads for a multi socket client?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, sockets

I understand that for most cases using threads in Qt networking is overkill and unnecessary, especially if you do it the proper way and use the `readyRead()` signal. However, my "client" application will have multiple sockets open (about 5) at one time. It is possible for there to be data coming in on all sockets at the same time. I am really not going to be doing any intense processing with the incoming data. Simply reading it in and then sending out a signal to update the GUI with the newly received data. Do you think a single thread application should be able to handle all of the data coming in?

I understand that I haven't shown you any code and that my description is pretty vague and it could very well depend on how it performs once implemented, but from a general design perspective and your guys' expertise, what is your opinion?

Answer (score 4):

Unless you are receiving really high-bandwidth streams (e.g. megabytes per second rather than kilobytes per second), a single-threaded design should be sufficient.  Keep in mind that the OS's networking stack is running "in the background" at all times, receiving TCP packets and storing the received data inside fixed-size in-kernel memory buffers.  This happens in parallel with your program's execution, so in most cases the fact that your program is single-threaded and busy dealing with a GUI update (or another socket) won't hamper your computer's reception of TCP packets.

The case where a single-threaded design *would* cause a slowdown of TCP traffic is if your program (via Qt) didn't call recv() quickly enough, such that the kernel's TCP-receive buffer for a socket became entirely filled with data.  At that point the kernel would have no choice but to start dropping incoming TCP packets for that socket, which would cause the server to have to re-send those TCP packets, and that would cause the socket's TCP receive rate to slow down, at least temporarily.  However, that problem can be avoided by making sure the buffers never (or at least rarely) get full.

The obvious way to do that is to ensure that your program reads all of the incoming data as quickly as possible -- something that QTCPSocket does by default.  The only thing you need to do is make sure that your GUI updates don't take an inordinate amount of time -- and Qt's widget-update routines are fairly efficient, so they shouldn't, unless you have a really elaborate GUI or an inefficient custom paintEvent() routine or etc.

If that's not sufficient, the next thing you could do (if necessary) is tell the OS's TCP stack to increase the size of its in-kernel TCP receive buffer, e.g. by doing:

```
 int fd = myQTCPSocketObject.descriptor();
 int newBufSizeBytes = 128*1024;   // request 128kB kernel recv-buffer for this socket
 if (setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, &newBufSizeBytes, sizeof(newBufSizeBytes)) != 0) perror("setsockopt");
```

Doing that would give your (single) thread more time to react before incoming packets start getting dropped for lack of in-kernel buffer space.

If, after trying all that, you still aren't getting the network performance you need, then you can try going multithreaded.  I doubt it will come to that, but if it does, it needn't affect your program's design too much; you'd just write a wrapper class (called SocketThread or something) that holds your QTCPSocket object and runs an internal thread that handles the reading from the socket, and emits a bytesReceived(QByteArray) signal whenever the thread reads data from the socket.  The rest of your code would remain approximately the same; just modify it to hold the SocketThread object instead of a QTCPSocket, and connect the SocketThread's bytesReceived(QByteArray) signal to a corresponding slot (via a QueuedConnection, of course, for thread-safety) and use that instead of responding directly to readReady().

Answer (score 1):

Implement it without threads, using a thread-considerate design(*), measure the delay your data experiences, decide if it is within acceptable bounds. Then decide if you need to use threads to capture it more rapidly.

From your description, the key bottleneck is going to be GUI reception of the "data ready" signal, render it. If you use the approach of sending lots of these signals, your GUI is goign to be doing more re-renders.

If you use a single-thread approach, you can marshal the network reads and get all the updates and then refresh the GUI directly. As you've described it, this sounds like it will have the least degree of contention.

(* try to avoid constructs which will require an entire rewrite if you go threaded, but don't put so much effort into making it thread-proof that it will actually need threads to make it efficient, e.g. don't wrap everything with mutex calls)

Answer (score 1):

I do not know much about Qt, but this could be a typical scenario where you use `select()` to multiplex multiple socket accesses with a single thread.

If the thread for selecting is used mainly for handling the data from/to the sockets you will be very fast(as you will have less context switches). So if you are not transfer really huge amounts of data it is likely possible that you will be faster will a single threaded solution.

That being said, i would go with the solution that fits the most for your needs, something that you can implement in a fair amount of time. Implementing `select` (async) can be quite a hassle, an overkill that might not be needed.

It's a C-like approach, but i hope i could help anyway.